# React. Abm. El usuario se elimina pero hay que actualizar la pagina para ver el cambio en la interfaz

Tags: reactjs

Tengo el siguiente problema en lo que estoy practicando. El problema es que cuando yo elimino un usuario al hacer click sobre un boton, el usuario se elimina, pero hay que actualizar la pagina para que ese usuario no se vea mas en la interfaz. Utilizo los hooks usecontext y usereducer.

Initial state

```
const initialState = {
    usuarios: [],
  };
```

Users Actions

```
  const borrarUsuarioAction = async (username) => {
    console.log(username);
    try {
      await clienteAxios.delete(`/api/account/${username}`);
      dispatch({
        type: USUARIO_ELIMINADO_EXITO,
        payload: username,
      });
      Swal.fire("Deleted!", "Your file has been deleted.", "success");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      dispatch({
        type: USUARIO_ELIMINADO_ERROR,
      });
    }
  };
```

Users Reducers

```
case USUARIO_ELIMINADO_EXITO:
      return {
        ...state,
        usuarios: state.usuarios.filter(
          (usuario) => usuario.username !== action.payload
        ),
      };
```

Componente Usuarios

```
<div>
      <h1>Usuarios</h1>
      {usuarios.length === 0 ? (
        <h1>No hay usuarios</h1>
      ) : (
        usuarios.map((usuario) => (
          <Usuario key={usuario.id} usuario={usuario} />
        ))
      )}
    </div>
```

Componente Usuario

```
<Fragment>
      <tr>
        <td>{userName}</td>
        <td>{email}</td>
        <td>
          <button
            className="btn btn-danger"
            onClick={() => eliminarUsuario(userName)}
          >
            Eliminar Usuario
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </Fragment>
```

Comment: estas seguro que el usuario se elimina del estado? podes inspeccionar el estado? podrias incluir la porcion de codigo donde mostras los datos?

Comment: Hola que tal. Al momento que hago el click en el boton no se elimina del state, tengo  que actualizar para ver el cambio en el state, de ahi lo que digo de la interfaz. que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ahi agregue donde muestro la informacion.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes mal el case `USUARIO_ELIMINADO_EXITO` en la linea donde realizas el filter, ya que, probablemente tu payload es un objeto que estás comparando con el username que es un string.

`case USUARIO_ELIMINADO_EXITO:
      return {
        ...state,
        usuarios: state.usuarios.filter(
          (usuario) => usuario.id !== action.payload.id //Yo usaría el id del usuario para comparar
        ),
      };`

Estoy asumiendo que tienes declarado tu estado como `const [state, setState] = useReducer..` y tu payload tiene una estructura como: `{id, username, roleId, etc}`

Comment: Hola. en el reducer era usuario.userName en vez de usuario.username como tenia jajajaj. gracias igual

Comment: de todas maneras, te recomiendo usar el ID del usuario para hacer la comparación, que bueno que lo hayas solucionado, saludos.

Comment: Pense lo mismo, pero me dice mi compañero que identity framework(back end en net core) trabaja mas que nada con username. gracias igual por el dato. saludos